# Initializing variables outside of PHP constructor

Tags: php, oop, constructor

I was looking through the PHP documentation and saw several comments where a variable was initialized outside of a class's constructor, similar to the following:

```
classMyClass {
    private $count = 0;

    public function __construct() {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

In *PHP Objects, Patterns, and Practice*, the author recommends using constructs only for the initialization of properties, deferring any heavy lifting or complex logic to specialized methods. This tutorial (a quick example that I found on Google) also recommends using constructors to initialize properties: http://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php/php-objects-page-3.php.

Why would you want to initialize a variable outside the constructor? Is this just sloppy coding, or is there a reason to do something like this? I have to say that until recently, I  initialized default values outside the constructor, and there doesn't seem to be any programmatic advantage of one way over the other.

Comment: It's just good programming practice.

Comment: when you just want to initialize simple variables it's quite clear doing it outside the constructor, for more complex initializations use the constructor

Comment: The example you have posted is providing a default value for the $count variable.  It is a good idea to provide a default value - this way you'll know what to test against to find out whether assignment in your constructor or elsewhere has succeeded.

Comment: With this the property will be declared and initialized even before the constructor was called.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you initialize a variable outside of the constructor, it must be initialized as a constant.  You can't do any operation to initialize it.  Thus, the initial value of that member is actually a part of the class signature.

For example, this is invalid:

```
private $var = $othervar;
private $var = func();
```

You could do it in the constructor as well, but it would be a bit more verbose and add some clutter to the constructor unless there was some sort of logic going on.

Comment: So there's no reason to *not* initialize a variable outside of the constructor if they are assigned a known value, such as a string?

Answer (score 2):

More a comment than an answer, but please elaborate here a little:

> Since it is recommended to use constructors for property initialization only,

Who says this and why? I assume the *only* relates to something else than property definitions with default values.

---

An answer part:

By default in PHP variables do not need to be defined because variables are then defined when first accessed in a write context. All variables, including undefined ones contain `NULL` ([Demo](http://codepad.org/zR3opT4B)):

```
class A {}

$a = new A;

var_dump($a->property); # NULL
```

Introducing class variables (properties) PHP then allowed to actually define variables. Those still return `NULL` by default, but they are *defined* ([Demo](http://codepad.org/8NN2oeHv)):

```
class A {
    public $property;
}

$a = new A;

var_dump($a->property); # NULL
```

In the next step of the evolution, this language construct also allows to specify a constant expression. That is constant because definition is compile-time (not run-time as the when the constructor is invoked). An example ([Demo](http://codepad.org/rI1yzAUY)):

```
class A {
    public $property = 'hello';
}

$a = new A;

var_dump($a->property); # string(5) "hello"
```

As this is compile- but your constructor run-time, I find it hard to compare both feature with another. Also it's not clear why you say that initializing via the constructor is recommended.

Comment: Please see my updates to my question - I added the source I had in mind for that claim.

Comment: Okay: A site with the name "Killer PHP" and the tagline "PHP Tutorials for Web Designers" might not go that much into detail as you would like to know. I can not see anything wrong in defining object properties. You can initialize later if you want, but you should define them. If their initial value should be something different than `NULL` but a constant expression, define them with the initial value. That is nothing wrong. Indeed, it makes your constructor less complicated which *is* a good thing. Constructors should be dumb, should not do much.

Comment: Thanks. I was mainly confused because I have seen good code primarily written with initialization outside the constructor, but it seems that most of the things that I have read have recommended initializing within the constructor. I can see how it is less cluttered (which is reason enough to do it), but I haven't found any other practical advantages in PHP for having setting a default value for instance property outside the constructor. THank you for your well thought-out answer.

Answer (score 0):

Far from sloppy... it's good programming practice. As you would also do in Java/C++, it just sets them up, and then you can do any initialisation in the constructor - usually to sent them to non-defaults as such.